# VBA - OptionButton Collection

Tags: vba, button, collections

I'm trying to get a collection of option buttons. I would like the objects of my collection to have the "OptionButton" type. Is there a way to do that ?

```
Private Sub SetInputs()

Dim OptionButtons As Collection
Set OptionButtons = New Collection

OptionButtons.Add (br_FKG1)

' MsgBox (TypeName(br_FKG1)) : OptionButton
' MsgBox (TypeName(OptionButtons.Item(1))) : Boolean

(...)

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: Got it.
If anybody has the same problem some day, just write `OptionButtons.Add br_FKG1` without the parentheses so that the object and not the value is added.

Comment: You can add this as an answer to your own question then accept it.

Comment: @AlexK. I saw that, but my reputation is not high enough yet, so I have to wait 8 hours after my question to answer myself. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. If anybody has the same problem some day, just write

```
OptionButtons.Add br_FKG1
```

without the parentheses so that the object and not the value is added.

Without parentheses, it is actually the default property of the class that is added. For an OptionButton, it is .Value, but it may be something else for other classes.